# ADNS3080 Optical Flow Sensor Reading Position with Raspberry pi-3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, opticalflow

I am using ADNS3080 optical flow in raspberry pi 3. I set SPI connection between raspberry and ADNS3080 optical flow. I used spidev library for reading values in python. I want to read delta_x and delta_y position which registers corresponding to 0x03 and 0x04 numbers in datasheet. So I am using this code for reading registers:

```
import spidev
import time
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
while True:
   resp = spi.xfer2([0x03, 0x04])
   print resp
   time.sleep(1)
```

I am taking "0,0" results in every loop. I have checked the connections hardware and there are no problems. What is the reason why I can't read these values?